# sum of second last column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I want to find the sum of the second last column of a file that has variable number of columns.

I know that if I knew that exact number of the column, I would be able to do -

```
 awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' mydatafile
```

for column `1`. But  not sure how I would do it if I didn't know the exact column number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [special variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03) `NF` refers to the number of fields per line in `awk`. To get the second last field you can access `$(NF-1)`:

```
awk '{s+=$(NF-1)} END{print s}' file
```